# Sending raw data with websocket, what is the best approach?

Tags: delphi, websocket

Using Delphi Berlin 10.2

We are using WebSocket in our application (with the component TsgcWebSocketClient). There are 2 ways to transmit data through this component, one using a method with String in parameter and another using TStream. We need to send raw data. So we are creating a TStream and send every time.
Is the best approach in your opinion?
We would like to send raw data without needing to convert in TStream every time.

The code is below.

What do you think??

```
procedure OnBinary(Connection: TsgcWSConnection; const Data: TMemoryStream);

procedure EnviarComando;    
var
 tmpBytes: TBytes;  
begin
   SetLength(tmpBytes, 5);
   tmpBytes[0] := 1;
   tmpBytes[1] := 2;
   tmpBytes[2] := 3;
   tmpBytes[3] := 13;
   tmpBytes[4] := $F3;
   tmpStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
   tmpStream.WriteBuffer(tmpBytes, 5);
   _webSocket.WriteData(tmpStream);
   tmpStream.Free;
 end;
end;
```

Tks in advance!

Comment: Ask the author of that component for support of `TBytes`. Currently it only can handle `string` or `TStream`. That design decision reaches several layers deep into the component architecture (see all the `DoWriteData...` methods in the code).

Answer (score 4):

Delphi has a [`TBytesStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBytesStream) class.  You don't need to copy the `TBytes` to a `TMemoryStream`, you can send the `TBytes` as-is instead:

```
procedure EnviarComando;    
var
  tmpBytes: TBytes;  
  tmpStream: TBytesStream;
begin
  SetLength(tmpBytes, 5);
  tmpBytes[0] := 1;
  tmpBytes[1] := 2;
  tmpBytes[2] := 3;
  tmpBytes[3] := 13;
  tmpBytes[4] := $F3;
  tmpStream := TBytesStream.Create(tmpBytes);
  try
    _webSocket.WriteData(tmpStream);
  finally
    tmpStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Otherwise, you can get rid of the `TBytes` and just `Write()` bytes directly into the `TMemoryStream`:

```
procedure EnviarComando;    
const
  cBytes: array[0..4] of Byte = (1, 2, 3, 13, $F3);
var
  tmpStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  tmpStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    tmpStream.WriteBuffer(cBytes, Length(cBytes));
    tmpStream.Position := 0;
    _webSocket.WriteData(tmpStream);
  finally
    tmpStream.Free;
  end;
 end;
end;
```

Or:

```
type
  TMemoryStreamAccess = class(TMemoryStream)
  end;

procedure EnviarComando;    
var
  tmpStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  tmpStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    TMemoryStreamAccess(tmpStream).Capacity := 5;
    tmpStream.WriteData(UInt8(1));
    tmpStream.WriteData(UInt8(2));
    tmpStream.WriteData(UInt8(3));
    tmpStream.WriteData(UInt8(13));
    tmpStream.WriteData(UInt8($F3));
    tmpStream.Position := 0;
    _webSocket.WriteData(tmpStream);
  finally
    tmpStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: ..or [TBinaryWriter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TBinaryWriter)